# using $http service, can not find the data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Here are my code -

```
var app = angular.module('chartApp', []);

app.controller('artistCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.artists = 
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=chart.gettopartists',
        params: {api_key: 'e8452c5962aafbb3e87c66e4aaaf5cbf', format: 'json'}
    }).success(function(result) {
        return result.data;
    });
    console.log($scope.artists);
}]);
```

How to view the original data from json file?

Comment: Please be more clear

Comment: try this   $scope.artists =  result.data; in success body

Comment: `$http` calls are by default asynchronous. The result you are working with is a so called *promise*, not the actual data. By the way `success` method is deprecated - you should use standard promise method `then()` instead.

Comment: What do you actually want? After the request is sent the response or say your callback or promise has whatever the server returned. Now use it the way you want to use, depending on the data being sent from that side.

Comment: to view the data in html , ng-repeat not working-  ng-repeat="a in artists.artist"

Comment: @AdityaGupta look at the answer added by Tarun, it was that simple..

Answer (score 2):

Move the assignment statement inside the success block:

```
.success(function(result) {
    $scope.artists = result.data;
})
```

Also, one more thing to note is the `console.log($scope.artists)` statement right after the `$http` block will still print `undefined` because it is executed before the promise is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this it will work :**

```
var app = angular.module('chartApp', []);

app.controller('artistCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.artists = 
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=chart.gettopartists',
        params: {api_key: 'e8452c5962aafbb3e87c66e4aaaf5cbf', format: 'json'}
    }).success(function(result) {
        $scope.artists = result.data;
    }).error(function(msg) {
        $scope.err = msg;
    });
}]);
```